# What's the exit status of a failed condition?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, exitstatus

```
[ $var -eq $val ]
```

What will be the value of `$?` after the above condition/test if it fails? Can I assume that it will **always** be `1`?

Edit: After reading answers I realized my question wasn't precise. I meant "will it be always `1` if no error occurs?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, at least as long as an error doesn't occur (so technically "no" in the general case, I guess?). See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_14:

> The following exit values shall be returned:
>
> - 0
>
>   *expression* evaluated to true.
> - 1
>
>   *expression* evaluated to false or expression was missing.
> - >1
>
>   An error occurred.

Or https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins:

> Evaluate a conditional expression *expr* and return a status of 0 (true) or 1 (false).

Answer (score 2):

No. it wont be always 1, if condition fails.

for eg:

```
[root@localhost ~]# [ xxxxxx15 -gt "$10" ]
bash: [: xxxxxx15: integer expression expected
[root@localhost ~]# echo $?
2
```

exit status may vary based on operator/conditions you have applied